# How can I make only the Start Screen show on a Windows Mobile 6.5 device?

Tags: windows-mobile-6.5

I have a couple applications for WinMo 6.5 that I have learned I can't put on the Today Screen, so now my question is how can I change the default view of the device to be showing the Start Screen rather than the Today Screen?

Comment: Although you can disable the Home screen, the WinMo does not handle this nice (redraw errors). I would go with a kiosk mode launcher (ie http://spb.com/pocketpc-software/kioskengine) or you start your own kiosk mode application launcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making changes to the registry for the today screen so that the "Contacts" and "Calendar" buttons are titled for and launch my apps. When the apps themselves launch I disabled the start menu and ok buttons to guide users to only have one app open at a time.